# Concurrency issues using bulkWrite on a MongoDb collection

Tags: mongodb, concurrency, pymongo

I use multiple processes, which run in parallel to update date in a MongoDb collection. I use something like this:

```
db.collection.bulkWrite(
   [
      { updateOne : <document> },
      { updateOne : <document> },
      { updateOne : <document> },
      { updateOne : <document> },
   ],
   { ordered : false }
)
```

The updateOne query often update the same document, but within the document different trees. My query looks something like this:

```
{
    '_id': 'ABC12345',
    'idents.tree.subtreeId': $anyIdHere,
}
```

and the set for the update:

```
{ '$set': {
    'idents.$.tree.entry': $newDictHere,
} }
```

If two processes now execute `bulkWrite` on the same document (i.e. `ABC12345`), but for different `subtreeIds`, the first `bulkWrite` and its `updateOnes` are not persisted in the document. Looks like there is a concurrency issue, but I do not know what is causing it. Are there any MongoDb limitations I might  be missing? I use pymongo any Python to execute the `bulkWrite`.

Comment: Can you provide minimal working examples of documents and updates ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your concurrency issue is related to the atomicity of document operations when 2 threads try to update the same document simultaneously.

[Link to MongoDB docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).